# How to convert WebLogicJtaTransactionManager to tomcat supported TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

As of now we are using weblogic server. So we are using webLogicJtaTransactionManager as shown below.

```
<bean id="transaction manager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager" >
<parameter="transactionManagerName" value="javax.transaction.TransactionManger" />
</bean>
```

Now i want to change above XML to tomcat supported transactionManger. Can you please help how to change this. I tried to deployee in tomcat server with out changing this i am getting below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not initialize WebLogicJtaTransactionManager because WebLogic API classes are not available; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.transaction.TransactionHelper
```

Comment: You could consider accepting answers or returning to some of your old questions. You seem to have lot of them lying aroung.

Answer (score 1):

For example [DataSourceTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) is platform agnostic.

In java config:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

// snip other stuff

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    // create and return a new JDBC DataSource ...
}
```

in xml config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
</bean>
```

Your weblogic example has JTA-enabled transaction manager, so it supports distributed transactions, and there is a cross-platform JTA transaction manager in Spring as well, [JtaTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html). However since Tomcat doesn't support JTA out of the box, you couldn't use that - using the example above you'll get transactions for your datasource only.